# FTP: Access to homedir and /var/www

Tags: centos, permissions, ftp, home-directory

I want a FTP user to have access to homedir and also `/var/www` directory

I have installed `vsftpd` via `yum` command and give them access to homedir.

To have access to a homedir only, I've set `chroot_local_user` to YES in `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`

I have tested it and it work fine, how to allow user to have access to `/var/www` as well and including write permission?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply change the DocumentRoot in Apache so that it is under the user's homedir? After all, /var/www is only a default, there's no reason it can't be changed generally speaking.

Comment: @ThatGraemeGuy I don't need homedir web. Its for two developers can upload files to /var/www  - default path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may so-called `bind` or remount part of the filesystem hierarchy somewhere else. In your case, you can create a `www` directory in your user's home directory and bind required directory there (assuming you do this under root user or other privileged user who is capable to run mount command, e.g. via sudo):

```
mkdir ~some_user/www
mount -o bind /var/www ~some_user/www
```

When you ftp under this user you will be able to traverse  the `/var/www` directory if the user have enough permissions.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. What about `ln` command?

Comment: No, symlinks can't work with chrooted environments. I mean symlinks pointing outside of the chroot environment as a symlink is just a "path" pointing sowhere  which is bound by the root directory which is user's home directory in this case.